# Clipping special characters to clipboard using command prompt

Tags: windows, batch, clipboard, special-characters, utf-8

I want to place a certain useful special character to the clipboard to use it. So I did this using a simple batch script, something like this:

```
@echo off

set /p char=<character.txt 
echo %char%| clip

exit
```

The `character.txt` contains a single character (pi) something like this:

> π

But when I run this batch script, it copies this to the clipboard:

> ΓêÜ

Why is this happening?

How can I copy this character normally?

Useful points-

- Both the `character.txt` and batch file are encoded in UTF-8.
- I use Notepad++ text editor.
- When I run `echo %var%> example.txt` , it copies the character normally to the text file, but for some reason it refuses to work with `| clip`

Answer (score 1):

[image]

---

```
@echo off

for /f "delims= " %%d in ('
forFiles/c "cmd /c echo(0xE3"')do set "_pi=%%~d"

echo\ %_pi% on your screen and in your clipboard : 
echo\ %_pi% in hexadecimal: 0xE3 | clip
```

- Test in your command line with your actual `chcp`:

  ```
  forfiles /c "cmd /c set/p "'=0xE3">nul| clip
  ```

---

You do not need to write a file to obtain this character, just try to use `forfiles` and define a desired character to output code in: `"cmd /c echo(0xE3"`

- Get hexadecimal `chcp` character table:

  **[437, 737, 775, 850, 852, 855, 857, 860, 861, 862, 863, 865, 866, 869](https://www.ascii-codes.com/)**
- For chcp 437 the Hexadecimal **`π == 0xE3`**:

[image]

---

- For check all chcp in your system in:
  **`HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Nls\CodePage`**
- Or, in command line run:

  **`reg query "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Nls\CodePage`**

---